# Expressjs to upload an image using multer saves an image in a weird format

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am trying to build an API which will take in image so used multer for that purpose, I am getting a success for uploading an image but it saves in some weird format not the actual format I tried to save.
I ll post the related code here.

in app.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
app.use(function(req, res, next) { //allow cross origin requests
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3001");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
});


app.use(express.static('../client'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(multer({dest:'./angular-src/src/assets/'}).single('file'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

In the API File

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
}).single('file');



router.post('/upload',function (req,res) {
   upload(req,res,function (err) {
       if (err){
           res.json({success:false});
           return;
       }else{
           // console.log(req.files[0].originalname);
           res.json({success: true, filename: req.file});
       }
   });
});


module.exports = router;
```

The stored image looks like this
[image]

The second one which has alpha numeric characters in it.

Image data is something like this

```
{
    "_type": "Project",
    "_id": "AAAAAAFF+h6SjaM2Hec=",
    "name": "Untitled",
    "ownedElements": [
        {
            "_type": "UMLModel",
            "_id": "AAAAAAFF+qBWK6M3Z8Y=",
            "_parent": {
                "$ref": "AAAAAAFF+h6SjaM2Hec="
            },
            "name": "Model",
            "ownedElements": [
                {
                    "_type": "UMLClassDiagram",
                    "_id": "AAAAAAFF+qBtyKM79qY=",
                    "_parent": {
                        "$ref": "AAAAAAFF+qBWK6M3Z8Y="
                    },
                    "name": "Main",
                    "visible": true,
                    "defaultDiagram": true
                },
```

This is how I am making a call from postman

[image]

Comment: I checked your code its storing image properly with the correct format, can you describe what problem you are facing?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Yes. It is the same

Comment: I am able to open it but the image data is weird. I ll post the image data here itself

Comment: Yes,this is the data at the destination where the image is being saved

Comment: @kgangadhar any solutions that you can give?

Comment: I tried your code locally its working perfectly for me. i am not getting any error check [this](https://gist.github.com/KarthikGangadhar/15b2853c2ab9b816a3434758a9877f35) out.

Comment: I dont have a UI in place as of now, I am sending the image using postman. I have added the postman image in the question only.

Comment: @downvoter why a downvote?

Comment: Can you check the API in postman if it is working with an image attachment?

Comment: Even in postman i am getting same result. its working fine. I think you are uploading `UMLClassDiagram` and for this image you are facing this issue. try with different image and check are you still getting same issue.

Comment: No, I tried to upload many different images but still I am getting the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved, for those who has similar kind off issue. What worked for me was doing

```
app.use(multer({dest:'./angular-src/src/assets/'}).single('file'));
```

in the API class itself.